# B+ Tree creation

Tags: data-structures, tree

I am trying to understand B+ trees. I have done some reading about it.
One thing I am confused about. For creation of tree some articles give no. of keys=n, no. of pointers=1+n and some increase them by 1.

For example I have to make a B+ tree of order 3 with
 6,2,9,16,12,17,21,18

Here the root shall have 3 numbers and 4 pointers OR 4 numbers and 5 pointers.

Comment: Some source says there are n+1 keys and n+2 pointers?

Comment: sorry decrease by 1, n pointers and n-1 keys. [link](http://ozark.hendrix.edu/~burch/cs/340/reading/btree/index.html)

Comment: Well it just depends whether N measures pointers or keys. It's not a conceptual difference. Strange way to express it though, and I'm not sure it's correct when you come to evaluate N/2 for node splitting.

Comment: Ok. So my first assumption is correct.  So when it says order 3, I'll take it as 3 keys and 4 pointers.  Can you point me to some correct examples so I can hit and try. And thanks for clearing stuff.

Answer (score -1):

The order measures the branching factor, or the maximum number of keys. When the root is alone it has one pointer, to its own key. Once more nodes are added it will have 1 pointer to its key and then *n* pointers to its children, where *n* is the order of the tree. In this case the B+ tree root will have one pointer to number (*key*) and up to 3 pointer to node. for a total of 4 pointers.

For more one b+ tree creation look at the insertion section:
[B+ Tree Insertion Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B+_tree#Insertion)

Comment: So if I get you correctly my tree would be    first level 9, second level (6),(12,16,17) third level [(2),(6)],[(9),(12),(16),(17,18,21)]

Comment: It doesn't have a 'pointer to its own key'. The pointers are to children, and there are n+1 of them because the keys fit between the pointers.